# Why does the pointer get incremented by a random value?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int arr[]={2,3,5,7};
int (*p)[4];
p=&arr;
cout<<p<<endl;
p++;
cout<<p<<endl;
```

Look at this simple piece of code where I'm trying to use a pointer to point to a whole integer array. The array contains 4 elements so it's size in memory should be 4*4=16 bytes. When I run it, the output is:

```
0x7ffe789ed080
0x7ffe789ed090
```

Expected output:

```
0x7ffe789ed080
0x7ffe789ed096
```

Answer (score 1):

Memory addresses are generally output in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). The number 16 is written in hexadecimal as `0x10`, which is the difference between those two numbers. It's just a different format than you were expecting.